# How to remove duplicate data from Prometheus

Tags: prometheus

I have a Prometheus which scrapes the data every 5 mins from a server. If a job runs more than 5 mins on the server, the Prometheus is scraping the data 2 times which results in duplication. Any suggestions on how to remove/avoid the duplicate data in Prometheus.

Answer (score 0):

For Prometheus that is not an issue. It was designed many metrics for a long time. We have 50k Metrics in our prometheus with data points every 30 over 30 days.